# How to pass more than one object in a private sub

Tags: vb.net

Okay I know the title is vague but I couldn't think of better title.

Anyways, to the question. I have a form and I want to make my buttons translucent. I do it by using `Color.FromArgb(ARGBValue, Color)`. I have to do this to many objects like buttons, labels, panels to make my application look attractive.

I have no problem in doing so but the thing is I want to do it at once. I don't want to repeat the line of code again and again which does the same thing, but for different object. So, I made a Sub procedure:

```
Private Sub TranslucentWorks(Sender As Object, ARGBValue As Integer, Color As Color)
    Sender.backcolor = Color.FromArgb(ARGBValue, Color)
End Sub
```

Here, the sender is an object whose background is to be made translucent.
This works all good as well. Now, the main problem is here. Let's say I have to make my two label controls translucent. I'd call the sub procedure when the form loads

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   TranslucentWorks(Line1Lbl, 30, Color.White
   TranslucentWorks(Line2Lbl, 30, Color.White)
End Sub
```

Imagine doing this again and again 20 times for 20 controls. Pretty boring, right?

So, I want to do it something like this:
`TranslucentWorks(Line1Lbl,Line2Lbl, 30, Color.White)`
I know the above code is wrong but you get the point. I want to make something like array of objects to be sent.

I tried putting `Sender() As Object` but it didn't work. Is there any way to do so?

*Please note that I am not using `WPF` at all so it has nothing to do with this.*

Comment: Put the controls in an array and do it in a loop

Comment: I would do that but i have to put the `ARGBValue` and `color` different at times. For example, I am using 30 for labels, I have to use 100 and color white for Panels.Before you say make different array for different controls, please notice that I have to keep different value even between same controls. I just want to know if there is any way to make array while passing the objects.

Comment: A [ParamArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/paramarray)?

Comment: how do I do that? can you tell me the basics about it?

Comment: Thank you @Plutonix. I did it using ParamArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to `Plutonix` for the help. I did it!

I set the sub procedure as :

```
  Private Sub TranslucentWorks(ARGBValue As Integer, Color As Color, ByVal ParamArray Senders() As Object)
    For Each Sender In Senders
        Sender.backcolor = Color.FromArgb(ARGBValue, Color)
    Next
End Sub
```

and called it like this:

```
 TranslucentWorks(30, Color.Purple, Line1Lbl, Line2Lbl)
```

Comment: Instead of `Senders() As Object` you should declare it `Senders() As Control`, since all GUI elements inherit from `Control`. That way you can access all properties without the overhead of late binding (which you have right now).

Comment: what do you mean by late binding?

Comment: What do you not understand about the information you found on the web when you searched for "vb.net late binding"?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/